# Reduce speed of drawer open

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `createDrawerNavigator` with `react-navigation` library.

How to reduce the speed of drawer open?

```
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
    },
    About: {
      screen: Screen2Stack,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
    drawerWidth: 300,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with current api.(https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4618)

I submitted a pr: (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-drawer/pull/14)